# Subsetting 2-D latitudes, longitudes and data from a big dataset in Python (IMS snowcover)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib-basemap

I have a "simple" objective in mind which turned out to be quite difficult to achieve. I have three 2-Dimensional arrays `lat`, `lon` and `data` all with dimensions (24576, 24576). The first two are latitudes and longitudes coordinates of the variable `data` which I'm trying to plot over a map. I'm reading all these data from a combination of binary files and text files so that any pre-processing operation is practically impossible and need to be done in the Python script.

Given the dimensionality of the array it is virtually impossible, because of the memory constraints, to directly plot the data even when choosing a basemap projection on a small area over the globe. I've already tried that and getting a memory error when trying to plot with `basemap.contourf`.

Thus, I need to subset the array BEFORE passing it to the contour function. I've tried many things, but nothing seems to work. My idea was to do something like this

```
lat_bnds, lon_bnds = [35, 50], [5, 20]
condition=((lats > lat_bnds[0]) & (lats < lat_bnds[1])) & (lons > lon_bnds[0]) & (lons < lon_bnds[1])
```

Where `lats` and `lons` are the 2-D coordinate arrays. This yields a 2-D boolean array which has the same dimension as `lats` (or equivalently `lons`) that I can then use to mask the original data but not to subset it.

Using the same condition in `numpy.where` produces an array shaped `(2, 2564856)` which I cannot use. I think the problem here is that there are multiple conditions that need to be satisfied in every point of the 2-D array and there is no guarantee that this will lead to a contiguous rectangular submatrix. However for the sake of plotting those data I really need to subset them, or to find another method to elaborate them.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there any other smart way to plot the original data without encountering any error?

**Sources of the data:** http://nsidc.org/data/G02156

**Brief script to read the data in assumed that you downloaded the necessary files:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap # Import the Basemap toolkit

with open('IMS1kmLats.24576x24576x1.double', 'rb') as f:
 data = np.fromfile(f, dtype='<d', count=24576*24576)
 lats = np.reshape(data, [24576, 24576], order='F')

with open('IMS1kmLons.24576x24576x1.double', 'rb') as f:
 data = np.fromfile(f, dtype='<d', count=24576*24576)
 lons = np.reshape(data, [24576, 24576], order='F')

widths=np.full((24576), 1, dtype=int).tolist()
data=np.array(pd.read_fwf('ims2017312_1km_v1.3.asc', skiprows=30, 
widths=widths, lineterminator='\n', header=None))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across this post while trying to plot IMS 1-km resolution data with Python I have a poor-man solution which will work fine.

The memory error is raised by the plot routines but the array can still be stored into python. So, instead of subsetting using a where function, I just tried to use explicit indexing like

```
lat_subset=lat[imin:imax, jmin:jmax]
```

and then plotting the result with plot.imshow() without doing a contour plot or use a map projection in order to have an idea of how the data were looking. This allowed me to choose the indices span in a way that my region of interest was inside. Now I was able to make the contour plot without having a memory error.

I have a small repository with a notebook which shows how to plot those data: https://github.com/guidocioni/snow_ims/blob/mistral/plot_ims.ipynb.
It has the advantage of read the file directly online although the coordinate files still need to be downloaded given their size.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you got an array of that shape, but consider that if you want a subset of the original array and you have your conditions, you can slice from the original list.

```
a = np.random.randint(10,50, size=(50,2))  # ---- generate coordinates

array([[44, 11],
       [40, 36],
       [19, 26],
       ..., 
       [33, 26],
       [42, 12],
       [15, 25]])

lats = a[:, 1]  # ---- latitude is Y-axis
lons = a[:, 0]  # ---- longitude is X-axis
lat_bnds, lon_bnds = [35, 50], [5, 20]  # ---- your desired bounds

condition =((lats > lat_bnds[0]) & (lats < lat_bnds[1])) & 
            (lons > lon_bnds[0]) & (lons < lon_bnds[1])

condition
array([False, False, False, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)

condition.shape  # => (50,)

a[condition]     # ---- slice the original array

array([[11, 45],
       [15, 40],
       [15, 43],
       [15, 49]])
```

Hope that gets you in the direction you want to go.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look into the question but unfortunately that doesn't help. I wish it could be that easy :(. The latitude and longitude are 2-d array on the original polar stereographic projection so that simply slicing them wouldn't do anything good. One needs to check every grid point where the condition is true and subset the array accordingly. I've added some additional information in the post that may help in reproducing the problem.

Comment: yes the sample data would have been useful.  If the points are projected into a sterographic projection, you might wish to report the bounding box coordinates in the same projection